How do I type the session and signIn callback in NextAuth route.ts file?
I'm trying to follow this Next.js app tutorial on youtube using TypeScript and MongoDB, but I'm running into a problem when initializing NextAuth (version ^4.24.7) using the Route Handlers method according to NextAuth documentation.
I don't know how to type the session and signIn callbacks and their arguments in TypeScript and am getting the errors
Type '({ session }: { session: any; }) => Promise' has no properties in common with type 'Partial'.ts(2559)
types.d.ts(45, 5): The expected type comes from property 'session' which is declared here on type 'AuthOptions'
and
Binding element 'profile' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Here is my app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts file:
import NextAuth, { Session, Profile } from 'next-auth';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';

import User from '@models/user'
import { connectToDB } from '@utils/database';


const handler = NextAuth({
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID as string,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string
        })
    ],
    async session({ session }) {
        const sessionUser = await User.findOne({
            email: session.user.email
        });

        session.user.id = sessionUser._id.toString();

        return session;
    },
    async signIn({ profile }) {
        try {
            await connectToDB();

            // check if a user already exists
            const userExists = await User.findOne({
                email: profile.email
            });

            // if not, create a new user
            if ( !userExists ) {
                await User.create({
                    email: profile.email,
                    username: profile.name.replace(" ", "").toLowerCase(),
                    image: profile.picture
                })
            }

            return true;

        } catch (error) {

            console.log(error);
            return false;
        }
    }
})

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };

and my models/user.ts file:
import { Schema, model, models } from 'mongoose';

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: [true, 'Email already exists!'],
        required: [true, 'Email is required!']
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Username is required!'],
        match: [/^(?=.{4,20}$)(?![_.])(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._]+(?<![_.])$/, "Username invalid, it should contain 4-20 alphanumeric letters and be unique!"]
    },
    image: {
        type: String
    }
});

const User = models.User || model("User", UserSchema);

export default User;

I've tried typing the session argument as Session like this:
async session({ session }: { session: Session }) {

But got these errors:
Type '({ session }: { session: Session; }) => Promise' has no properties in common with type 'Partial'.ts(2559)
'session.user' is possibly 'undefined'.ts(18048)
I've also tried typing the profile argument as Profile:
async signIn({ profile }: { profile: Profile }) {

But got this error:
'profile.name' is possibly 'undefined'.ts(18048)
